# How do I setup a GitHub action that runs pytest with pipenv?

Tags: python, github, pytest, pipenv, github-actions

I have a Python project that uses [pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to run [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/). I want to create a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/actions) that will run pytest each time I submit a pull request.

I've tried using the [python-app.yml](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/ci/python-app.yml) starter workflow.

```
name: Python application

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        pip install flake8
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pip install pytest
        pytest
```

But I get the following build failure.

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I would like to avoid creating a `requirements.txt` file and simply use pipenv to run pytest.

How do I create a GitHub Action that uses pipenv to run pytest?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Install [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) first and then you can run pytest using pipenv.

```
name: Python application

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set up Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Install pipenv
        run: pip install pipenv
      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          pipenv install --dev
          pipenv run pytest
```

Comment: What's the difference between `dschep/install-pipenv-action@v1` and `pip install pipenv`

Comment: @MoK Looks like `dschep/install-pipenv-action@v1` is basically running `pip install pipenv` with a few additional changes (e.g. running in `sudo`): https://github.com/dschep/install-pipenv-action/blob/master/src/main.ts.

Comment: @MoK `pip install pipenv` on its own works just fine. I added a second option to my answer.

Comment: Thanks!, running `pipenv run pytest . ` instead of just `pytest . ` resolves my issue of `pytest not found`

Comment: shouldn't we use `pipenv sync --dev` instead of `pipenv install --dev` ?

Comment: What's `pipenv sync --dev` do?

Answer (score 1):

Note: The [dschep/install-pipenv-action](https://github.com/dschep/install-pipenv-action)  action listed in a previous answer is archived.

An alternative is  [palewire/install-python-pipenv-pipfile](https://github.com/palewire/install-python-pipenv-pipfile)  which installs python and pipenv.

Example using it to run pytest:

```
name: Project Tests
on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main 
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Python, pipenv and Pipfile packages
        uses: palewire/install-python-pipenv-pipfile@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.10.0
      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          pipenv install --dev
          pipenv run pytest
```

The pipenv install in the above script assumes that pytest is listed under the [dev-packages] section of the project's Pipfile.